# Android : Not able to do canvas painting on image uploaded from sd card

Tags: android, android-canvas, touch-event

I am trying to build a paint application.
The application is divided into 3 parts:

1. Initially the application is having a white background and user can paint on the canvas using different brush sizes and different colors
2. User can save the canvas image to sd card
3. User can upload the image from sd card and again paint on the image

Point 1 and 2 are working fine and I am able to paint on a white background.
But point 3, when I upload any image from Gallery and try to paint on the image, then the previous path painted is getting disappeared and only new path is displayed.

code :

```
onDraw(Canvas canvas){
  mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
  mPath = new Path();
  mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
  canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
  canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
  canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}

onTouch - >

case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                mPath.reset();
                mPath.moveTo(x, y);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
                float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
                if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                    mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                    mX = x;
                    mY = y;
                }
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
                mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
                mPath.reset();
                break;

mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath); -----this is from sd card
```

Comment: Are you sure the image is saved with all the extra drawn modifications before it is reopened for new edits? Can you post some of the code that does all this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that your app is keeping the previous drawn path and also drawing the new path. The reason for this is that each time when the onDraw() method is called you are creating a new bitmap and drawing path on that and you are also not saving the previous paths as you are calling **mpath.reset()**. 
There is one more point and it's very important: Never Never! call createBitmap() method in iteration. It consumes a lot of memory and will lead to **outOfMemory** exception.
The solution to you'r problem is:

- Create a bitmap(should be mutable) from any stream(SD card,drawable,etc) or an empty bitmap in the constructor of your custom view and then create a canvas and use the same bitmap to draw into. In your touch_up() method draw paths on this canvas. In the onDraw() you should use this bitmap as the specified bitmap for the canvas(passed as parameter, no need to create a new canvas here) to draw into.

Here you can follow this [link](http://pastebin.com/fCv0P10y) to the android api demo code.

Comment: The path is drawn fine in case of a blank background (when my bitmap is not containing any image. As soon as I say mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath) [which is image uploaded from the sd card] and in onDraw() -> canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint) the previously drawn path is getting erased. I am calling createBitmap in the constructor on my view class.